# when abstract class doesn't contain any abstract method

Tags: java

I am still confused when abstract class doesn't contain any abstract method, what a purpose of it? why don't use regular class rather than abstract class if it doesn't contain any abstract method ? In fact, I was saw this situation is applied on java and libgdx library or perhaps for every library. 
So, because this situation,  I was thinking  is it very important to know why use abstract class without abstract method rather than regular class.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a class `abstract` (either with or without abstract methods), you are forcing the users of this class to create concrete sub-classes of it, since they can't instantiate it.

Comment: This is obvious. The question is: why would you want to do that? Your `abstract class` already implements all methods. Of course, the user may overwrite them when extending the `abstract class`, but why deny her/him the instantiation of your `abstract class`? Can you think of a good use case for this?

Comment: Scalability, in a nutshell.

Comment: @Bathsheba was this comment a response to mine? If so, would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: The only possible answer can be " The base class has something to offer to all it's children". The derived classes are free to have their own implementations but the base implementation would still serve "some" purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A user of an `abstract` class *must* create a concrete derived class.

This can be useful since it allows the author of an `abstract` class to introduce abstract functions at a later date. The amount of refactoring necessary at that time is then significantly reduced.